# jQuery: Getting syntax error after split() or text()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax-error

What I need to do is grab the first `<p>` tag within an element, loop through all of the words, and wrap them in `<span>` tags. I wrote a script for this, which I thought worked, but it appears to break when some characters are in the `<p>` tag. I don't know which character(s) that causes it to break though.

Here is my current code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
// Transform is set on html tag by modernizr
// Apply this on all .quote boxes, even if there are multiple (most likely aren't)
$('.csstransforms .quote').each(function() {
    // Get data
    var elem = $(this).find('p:first'),
        html = elem.text(),
        words = html.split(" "),
        charCount = html.length

    $(this).append('<p class="fixed"></p>');

    // Add new words
    var tmpWord = '';
    for(i=0; i< words.length ; i++) {
        tmpWord = $.trim(words[i]);

        if(tmpWord && tmpWord != "") {
            // Maybe replace with $(elem).next('.fixed') or something?
            $('.csstransforms .quote .fixed').append('<span>'+ tmpWord +' </span>');   
        }
    }

    // Check word count, make size smaller if needed
    if(charCount > 150) {
        // Add class to .quote box
        $(this).addClass('smaller');
    }

    // Hide original <p>
    $(elem).hide();
});
});
```

The error i'm getting is as follows, and what you see in the text is the actual quote:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: "In the decade or so, science has discovered a tremendous amount about the role emotions play in our lives. Researchers have found that even more than IQ, your emotional awareness and abilities to handle feelings, will determine your success and happiness in all  walks of life, including family relationships". – John Gottman, Ph. D.
```

Any ideas as to what is causing this, and how to fix it? Been chewing on it on a while without success.

**Update:** Jsfiddle showing same error: http://jsfiddle.net/Uugbc/

Comment: Made a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) that shows the error.

Comment: Try adding a semicolon after charCount = html.length

Comment: @epascarello The error is already posted? It's basically just saying "Syntax error".

Comment: Can you post your html, i can't recreate this.

Comment: @prc322 I was hoping that would fix it, but unfortunately not... no difference.

Comment: @aziz.punjani Give me a minute, i'll see what i can do.

Comment: @aziz.punjani and everyone else, see OP for jsfiddle snippet.

Comment: @mplungjan semicolons are mandatory in several places, whenever [the rules for automatic insertion](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-7.9) would not behave as desired.

Comment: @prc322 semicolons are obviously not required since you can write an entire script without them. there are lots of opinions on whether they should be standard.

Comment: @mplungjan: Semicolons are not required as testing your code is not required. You don't have to do it but it's better if you do and one source of mistakes less you have to care about. My comment might be rough but it's the truth, so I won't edit it.

Comment: Well, after you simply just stated my comment as your answer there's no need to fire back at me, right?

Comment: Please look again. I looked at the jsFiddle and it was not the missing semicolon but the fact that he had charCount = $(html).text().length; that was the problem. [My test fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/zATN8/) works with or without the semicolon!!! The code in the post above does not reflect the issue he had in his fiddle!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just for clarification. Your fiddle has
`charCount = $(html).text().length;`
but your variable `html` is not a jQuery object.

This will work better

```
    var elem = $(this).find('p:first'),
        html = elem.text(),
        words = html.split(" "),
        charCount = html.length; // here you had $(html).text().length;
```

Comment: Success! Thanks a bunch mplungjan!

Comment: Isn't that exactly what I said?

Comment: prc322 go look at the code on jsfiddle, it was this before `$(html).text().length` and now it's `html.length`. That's what the answer above is in context to.